# cell-area or cell-card primary and secondary

Tags: bixby

I write some code layout for bixby, As you know there has primary and secondary property.

In image-card object format like this.

```
      image-card {
        size (L)
        title-area {
          hAlign (Start)
          slot1 {
            text {
              value("#{value(data)}")
              style(Title_M)
            }
          }
          slot2 {
            single-line {
              text {
                value("#{value(data)}")
                style(Detail_L)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        image-url ("https://SOME_DOMAIN.com/SOME_IMAGE.png")
      }
```

But in cell-area format like this.

```
      cell-area {
        slot1 {
          image {
            url ("https://SOME_DOMAIN.com/SOME_IMAGE.png")
            shape (Square)
          }
        }
        slot2 {
          content {
            primary ("#{value(data)}")
            secondary ("#{value(data)}")
          }
        }
      }
```

It looks like cell-area have no property like style, is it right? or it can be modified like image-card, style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:(5/24/2021)**
This was a while ago. I'm not working on Bixby now. Bixby is a very dynamic and fast evolving Voice Platform.
There may be a better way to do this in latest Bixby Platform.
Please refer to the documentation and reach out to the technical support team.

**Original Answer**

Based on the documentation, looks like Image Card is clickable and is meant for using images as background (vs Cell Card) where as Cell Area is not clickable and meant for creating a cell in a container (Parent Layout).

I guess to show this intrinsic difference to user intuitively (& may be automatically), Cell Area  inherits Parent's style and blends in but using Image Card, developer can choose to "trigger" clicking intuition by customizing the appearance using style element.

I hope this helps!

PS. Download this capsule where you can see the various layouts in action: https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/common-layouts

Comment: Thanks for your help but there is no way to customizing font on cell-area or cell-card. even user phone set different font in user's phone, then my cell-area's font is belong to user's chosen font.

Comment: For Image-Card, there is a way to customize the style. https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout-macro-def.content.image-card.title-area.slot1.text.style. Not a full range freedom but to some extent.

Comment: Unfortunately I must use cell-card for my capsule, not image-card. and cell-card or cell-area font customizing is not permitted.
Thanks for your answer.